# An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request in cosmos db and asp.net core

Tags: sql, asp.net-web-api, azure-cosmosdb, asp.net-core-webapi

I am creating a web api using asp.net core and cosmos db. i wrote a query and try to execute it .but i got the following error.I upload all my code by images . please help me.
[image]
[image]
 [image]

Comment: Post code/errors as text instead of images of text

Comment: I post like this because of better understand .

Comment: _...because of better understand..._ Actually it is the opposite of that

Comment: but . i post the same question with code . no one help me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56438013/an-unhandled-exception-occurred-while-processing-fetchlistasyncnullableguid-i

Comment: if you can please help.

Comment: sorry .i did not understand. i followed a document . they did in the same way

Comment: The error is "resource not found" so probably wrong identifier or wrong collection or something like that. Are you sure name is catlogdb and not catalogdb? What document are you referring to?

Comment: this same collection link .working  for post and delete . for this only not working

Comment: https://github.com/mattruma/CosmosDBWebApi    this is the code i am using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stack trace points to a NotFound in OperationType Read, ResourceType Collection. This means that the Uri that you are passing, is not pointing to a collection that exists in that account.

You are creating the Uri using:

`UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(_azureCosmosDbOptions.Value.DatabaseId, "catlogdb")`

Check the value of `_azureCosmosDbOptions.Value.DatabaseId` and verify it is valid and it's the one you expect, and double check if within that Account, there is a "catlogdb" collection within that database.

The repository link you provide in the comments does not match the code in your screenshots, there is no mention of `catlogdb` in that entire repository.

For the future, please do not post images, it makes it really hard to copy parts of your code to provide an answer.

Comment: i changed it . now i got following error.  var datalist = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(result); can you please help me.

Comment: What is the error? You just shared a code line that shows how you are calling JsonConvert.

Comment: Don't edit your posts completely and change the question, otherwise it makes the answers totally unrelated to your current question. If the original error was fixed with my answer, mark the answer, and then create a new post with the new issue.